# JS variables getting "stuck" on new page with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, turbolinks

First, let me apologize for the complexity of this question, I can't really break it down more simply as the complexity might be part of the cause. But this logic makes the active link for the page light up and flicker.

Using turbolinks, on the first page everything works fine, but when we switch to another page, things start going haywire. The link that previously had the class of `active` from the previous page will still be saying its passed in argument of `active` is `true`, even though it no longer has a class of `active`.

With turbolinks disabled, everything works as expected.

```
function flicker(elem, active) {
  var delay = Math.random() * (2000) + 130;

  console.log($(elem).data('name') + ": " + active + ': ' + $(elem).hasClass('active'));
  if (active == true) {
    // We need specific timers for each link so each can operate with its own
    // separate "thread" and be toggled independently of the others.
    // Using window['foo'] to handle dynamic variable names.
    window['timer-' + $(elem).data('name')] = setTimeout(function() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(elem).addClass('powered');
      }, 20) // Controls length of flicker.
      flicker(elem, true);
      $(elem).removeClass('powered');
    }, delay);
  } else {
    clearTimeout(window['timer-' + $(elem).data('name')]);
  }
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // Initiate the current, active link.
  $('.navbar a.active').each(function() {
    window['timer-' + $(this).data('name')]; // Instantiating dynamic variable.
    flicker($(this), $(this).hasClass('active'));
  });
});
```

Stay with me. So where I have the console log on line 3, on the first page, that will output as expected. For example:

```
nav-1: true: true
```

will repeatedly get output with each flicker, indicating that the first link `active` argument from line 1 is `true` and that it has a class of `true`.

But if I click on the second link to go to the next page, then console will repeatedly log:

```
nav-1: true: true
nav-2: true: true
```

Even though, in this case, `nav-1` does *not* have a class of `active`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was able to fix this just by resetting all flickering effects on page load.

```
$('.navbar a').each(function() {
  flicker($(this), false);
});
```

Works with turbolinks now.